# JavaScript Error: e is null popup during Selenium Test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have test which is resulting in a Firefox pop-up which looks like this:

[image]

The exception is an InvalidOperationException and it goes on to say
**JavaScript Error: "e is null"** then making reference to a JavaScript file called **commandprocessor.js**

I am using the 2.44.0 version of WebDriver with Firefox version 33.

Out of completeness, I will also add that this pop-up is not throw on if a user manually follows the steps in that test.

Any ideas what is going on? Previous SO questions with similar error have yielded no answer.

Comment: I believe I have found the answer and always hate to be the one to answer my own questions (rare). In one of the callbacks, the code included ---- $('#confirmRegistration').attr('href', 'javascript:location.reload();'); ---- When I commented it out, the error went with it. Now, I just need to write an alternative to what that was doing. Thanks for the suggestion @shri046 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of the callbacks, the code included

```
$('#confirmRegistration').attr('href', 'javascript:location.reload();');
```

Seems to be forcing a page reload, which the WebDriver did not like.

Answer (score 1):

Could be an issue with the driver itself. Have you looked at these issues logged with selenium webdriver?

[Issue 7977:    Upredictable javascript errors "e is null"](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7977)
[Issue 8095:    fxdriver.error.toJSON fails to match qualified method names containing $](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8095)

Based on the [rev logs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/list?r=1b8e7c08c12666ba58420d7f9f20463d24754aa9) these fixes seemed to have been added after 2.44.0 release so they may not have made it yet to a release version.